# jsonp comet hanging request causes ugly "loading" status on browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, comet, jsonp, long-polling

I'm using jsonp to do cross-domain comet requests, and the "loading" status is really annoying.

Is there any way to suppress this with javascript?

For those who are unfamiliar with jsonp, it basically injects a script tag, except in my case, I'm hanging the request on my server without returning the request until a later time.

During this time, browsers see my request as a "loading" state.

I am using this: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to suppress the loading status using Javascript, regardless of why you have it.

However, there is at least one alternative for cross-domain COMET which wouldn't trigger the loading status in the first place. XMLHttpRequest doesn't set the loading status and, according to my tests, the CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) spec which allows cross-domain XHR is pretty well supported.

Basically, support is as follows: (According to a mix of browser documentation and my own tests for a project I'm working on)

Full support in:

- Gecko 1.9.1+ (Firefox 3.5, SeaMonkey 2.0, etc. Tested good Firefox 3.6.8 and SeaMonkey 2.0.7)
- WebKit (Safari 4+, Chrome 3+, etc.. Tested working on Safari 4 on OSX, Safari 5 on WinXP, Chrome 5.0.375.127 (Stable channel), [Midori](http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php?/pages/midori_summary.html) 0.2.7, the new [Flock](http://www.flock.com/), [Epiphany](http://projects.gnome.org/epiphany/) 2.30.2, [luakit](http://luakit.org/projects/luakit/), and [uzbl](http://www.uzbl.org/))

Untested, but should be fully supported:

- [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) (WebKit-based MacOS alternative to [Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) and Chrome's "Create Application Shortcuts...")

Limited support in:

- Internet Explorer 8 (Microsoft implemented an XDomainRequest() object instead and, using security as an excuse, didn't implement the flag to pass credentials and cookies with the request)
- [Sleipnir](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Sleipnir_%28web_browser%29) (Support is determined by which version of MSHTML it's embedding)

Notably unsupported:

- Opera (As of 11.01.1190, no support whatsoever)
- Camino (As of 2.0.5, still based on Gecko 1.9.0 (Firefox 3.0))
- [Arora](https://code.google.com/p/arora/) (As of 0.10.2, inherits WebKit's CORS API but has a bug that causes requests to fail)
- old, Mozilla-based Flock (Based on Gecko 1.9.0 (Firefox 3.0))

It's not a complete list, but it's every browser with userscript support I could find to test. I've already taken the time to cite my sources on the [CORS wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) if you want them.

The simplest solution I can think of would be to [test for CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) and then fall back to JSONP so that people using a modern browser get a perfect experience and people using something older see the loading status as an unavoidable side-effect.

Here's the MDC page on [how CORS works](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control).

Answer (score 2):

If you *begin* your first request *after* the page has finished loading, you should be able to avoid the loading indicator.

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.jsonp(...)
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but as I remember, my tests showed that Firefox and Chrome differed on that point.

Comment: I tried this, but this does not work in Chrome.  Maybe b/c I'm also running an ajax request immediately after the page load which takes longer for the page to finish rendering?